Intersection of superellipse with line
My goal is to do a stereographic-like projection of the plane but on a $L_p$ sphere and with the projection between the pole and the center of the sphere. For that I begin with 2D stereographic-like projection of the real line on a superellispe (first with the same radius in both direction to keep thing simple ^^) with the projection between the pole and the center of the superellispe.
So I would like to find the intersection points of a superellispe (with the same radius in both direction) and a line.
The equation of the superellipse is
$|x|^n + |y|^n = R^n$
and the line is
$y = ax + b$
By injecting directly the equation of the line into the equation of the superellipse or vice versa I end up with a degree $n$ polynomial which I can't manage to find the roots of...
I also know that the parametric equation of a superellipse is
$r(\varphi) = \frac{R}{\sqrt[n]{|\cos(\varphi)|^n + |\sin(\varphi)|^n}}$
where $\varphi$ is the angle with respect to the horizontal line, or
$\begin{cases}
x(\lambda) = R\operatorname{sign}(\cos(\lambda))|\cos(\lambda)|^\frac{2}{n} \\
\\
y(\lambda) = R\operatorname{sign}(\sin(\lambda))|\sin(\lambda)|^\frac{2}{n} \\
\end{cases}$
where $\lambda$ is NOT the angle with respect to the horizontal line.
But I can't find the values of $\varphi$ or $\lambda$ that corresponds to the intersection points...
If anyone knows how to handle this problem (or a theorem saying there are no closed form)
